# Do I need negative lookahead to extract TEST strings in my regular expression?

Tags: regex, apache, cookies, regex-lookarounds

My goal is to remove tokens from the string below that do not start with "TEST" with the help of regular expressions.

```
TESTA=abc; VAL2=def; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl; VAL2=bla1; VAL3=bla2
```

Based on reading online it seems I would need to create a regular expression that will match what I want and then use negative lookahead for it. However, I am unable to come up with one.

- Input string:

  ```
  TESTA=abc; VAL2=def; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl; VAL2=bla1; VAL3=bla2
  ```
- Matching string:

  ```
  TESTA=abc; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl;
  ```

Is it even possible to do what I want in a single regular expression?

We need this to place in our Apache conf file. Some of the cookies sent to Apache are so big that it is failing our application. The approach we are trying to take is to filter all the cookies not set by our application. We can enforce some sort of restriction that all our cookies start with specific prefix (as used in the example above) and we will filter the rest.

In Apache if I use the syntax below it will replace the cookie that has a key TESTC and its value from the string with empty string. I can enhance the regex to match is with key that starts with TEST_. So basically it can remove the following :> "; TEST_key:VALUE FOR Cookie" . However what I want is the exact opposite of it. Leave alone what matched and replace everything else with empty string.

RequestHeader edit Cookie "(^TESTC=[^;]*; |; TESTC=[^;]*)" ""

Comment: You should always post what you have tried so that others can point out what you missed and how you can improve the code.

Comment: Should bla2 have a semicolon afterwards? That would match the rest of the values...

Comment: What is the language? Without it, the question is more than unclear.

Comment: Modified my question with more information. The regex needs to go in Apache  conf file

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
[^=;]+(?<!TEST.)=[^;]+(?:$|;)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rY4sS9/1)

---

**What it does?**

- `[^=;]+` Matches till the first `=` or `;`
- `(?<!TEST.)` Negative lookbehind. Checks if the string matched is preceded not by `TEST.`
- `=[^;]+` If the lookbehind is successful, Matches till the next `;`

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Non-Greedy Quantifier

You don't need anything as complicated as zero-width assertions or negative lookahead or lookbehind. All you need is a non-greedy quantifier like `*?` in engines that support it. For example, at the Bash prompt and only using egrep:

```
$ echo 'TESTA=abc; VAL2=def; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl; VAL2=bla1; VAL3=bla2' |
  egrep -o 'TEST.*?;' | xargs

TESTA=abc; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl;
```

You can do something similar in Ruby, Python, or Perl. For example, using Ruby:

```
str = 'TESTA=abc; VAL2=def; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl; VAL2=bla1; VAL3=bla2'
str.scan(/TEST.*?;/).join " "
#=> "TESTA=abc; TESTB=ghi; TESTC=jkl;"
```